# Height of UItableViewCell Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static

I use `UITableView` to show some message, and the cells have different height. It works well before we upgrade the project to `swift3`.

**Issue :**

If I run same project in `iOS 8.1` , the `UITableView` will show with the wrong height 44(default cell height).

I test that the `UITableView` will call

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

method every time before `-viewDidAppear` and after `-viewWillAppear`

method, to calculate the height of every first cell in the session.

**Output :** [Printed Height Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9AN.png)

Test with `iOS 9.3`, it never call the method after the `UITableView` was first loaded.

I think it is the reason why give me the wrong height, but why it calls?

Comment: Question is uncleared. So windup post and again write clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**Implement this `UITableViewDelegate` methods :**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**and**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: yes, it works with constraints that specify in storyboard. And, do you known why it cause ?

Comment: @CSwater I am not getting you.

Comment: I did as you say , and make sure the cell has certain height constraint , then get the cell's right height.  …… I will try my best to improve my English (-_-#)

Comment: @CSwater The above two methods I have posted in my answer, automatically calculates the each cell row height even they have different height. But if depends on your constraints too.

Comment: I am still confused. You know, UITableView with static cell property, means the datas on the tableView will be store as static data, including the value of the height 。But why it returns a wrong height to the cell ? I use static table view for many times, and had never seem like this before;

Comment: Post your code bro or mail me your project, Without it I can't do anything.

Comment: I found it is easy to recur this bug , you can get the demo on my github :  [Demo](https://github.com/CSwater2016/Test) (Run on iOS8.1 simulator)

Comment: Your project is blank, first lean something about `UITableView`

Comment: what do you mean about `blank`? There has no dataSource in the project or the project contains nothing ? For the former, I use static TableView in this project so that you can see the dataSource in the file `Main.storyboard` , it can be run on iOS8.1 in swift3.   And the latter, I can sure it contains the complete project. Thanks for your patience !

Comment: @CSwater For using the `UItableView` you have to  implement its `delegate method`and write code there. Its not all like a `UILabel` and `UItextField`where you drag and drop component and run your project and appears on the `simulator`.

Comment: @CSwater `Go with these two tutorials.` **1)** [How-to-create-custom-tableview](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/) **2)** [tableview-dynamic-cell-height](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Comment: It seems like a course about a dynamic usage of  tableView. I use in that way if need, but for some simple pages , I prefer the static usage. Static usage of a tableView can show the component we drag like the describe of the `UILabel` and `UITextField` as you say.

Comment: By the way, have you run this project successfully? If you did, it can show you the same page as it make in storyboard.

Comment: Yeah! you arrange you can cell from `storyboard` but you have to implement delegate methods, without this your `tableview` doesn't work whether you are creating static & dynamic page.